# Display table results in a collapsible tree in AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display results from databse using AngularJs and display it in a collapsible tree. Below are my scripts.

**AngularJs Controller**

```
ViewReportsController: function (scope, routeParams, resourceFactory, location, route) {
            scope.reports = [];
            scope.type = routeParams.type;
            //to display type of report on breadcrumb
            var typeReport = routeParams.type.replace(routeParams.type[0], routeParams.type[0].toUpperCase()) + " " + "Reports";
            scope.type = typeReport;

            scope.routeTo = function (report) {
                location.path('/run_report/' + report.report_name).search({reportId: report.report_id, type: report.report_type});
            };

            if (!scope.searchCriteria.reports) {
                scope.searchCriteria.reports = null;
                scope.saveSC();
            }
            scope.filterText = scope.searchCriteria.reports;

            scope.addLocaleReportName = function (){
                if(document.getElementsByName("locale_name") != undefined && scope.reports){
                    if(scope.reports[0].report_locale_name == undefined){
                        var result = document.getElementsByName("locale_name");
                        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                            scope.reports[i].report_locale_name = result[i].value;
                        }
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.reports));
                    }
                    scope.onFilter();
                }
            };

            scope.filterByReportSubType = function(report) {
                return !(report.report_subtype === 'Triggered');
            }

            scope.onFilter = function () {
                scope.searchCriteria.reports = scope.filterText;
                scope.saveSC();
            };

            if (routeParams.type == 'all') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'FullReportList', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'savings') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Savings', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                }); 
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'timedeposit') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Time Deposit', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });             
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'loans') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Loan', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'shares') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Shares', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                }); 
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'accounting') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Accounting', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'clients') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Client', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                }); 
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'funds') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Fund', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });                 
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'application') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Across Application', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });
            } else if (routeParams.type == 'teller') {
                resourceFactory.runReportsResource.get({reportSource: 'reportCategoryList', R_reportCategory: 'Teller Management', parameterType: true, genericResultSet: false}, function (data) {
                    scope.reports = scope.getReports(data);
                });             
            }

            // Remove the duplicate entries from the array. The reports api returns same report multiple times if it have more than one parameter.
            scope.getReports = function (data) {
                var prevId = -1;
                var currId;
                var reports = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    currId = data[i].report_id;
                    if (currId != prevId)
                        reports.push(data[i]);
                    prevId = currId;
                }
                return reports;
            };
        }
```

Current display using table format. But i want to change this in Collapsible Tree

**Table View**

```
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr class="graybg">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="pointer-main" ng-repeat="report in reports| orderBy:'report_name':reverse | filter:filterByReportSubType">
                    <td class="pointer" data-ng-click="routeTo(report)">{{''+report.report_name</td>
                    <td class="pointer" data-ng-click="routeTo(report)">{{report.report_type}}</td>
                    <td class="pointer" data-ng-click="routeTo(report)">{{report.report_category}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Format i would like to implement is like http://plnkr.co/edit/l8uzoOSiu0AA7phytnYi?p=preview

- Loans

  - Disbursed

    - List of Disbursements
    - List of Disbursements1
    - List of Disbursements 3
    - Loan Loss Provisions
  - Savings

    - List of Savings
    - List of by Product

Comment: What is the question? Also note that we have no idea what your data structure looks like

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl, I have edited it, hope its clear now